# Visual studio code formatting with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx

When I am working in react native and in react.js, my **components** are not colored green. I tried going to **code > Preferences > Color Theme >** and setting it to **Dark+** , but the components are still highlighted blue.

Also when I do the command
`⌘ /`  (to create a comment) it does the javascript way of leaving comments:  `//this is a comment`
instead of  `{/* comment */}` .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the `Babel Javascript` extension (in my case it was `Babel ES6/ES7`). It has problems with JSX. Removing this extension fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom bar where it says Javascript (Babel) if you click that it will give you language options. Select Javascript React instead and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut to use multiline comment is `Option(⌥) + Command (⌘) + /` or

you could use `CMD + SHIFT + A` .

One way to check your shortcuts is to go to

- Command palette (SHIFT + CMD + P)
- Type keyboard shortcuts > Open Keyboard shortcuts
- In the table look for the keybinding for `toggle block comment` to find the shortcut.